# Code to replace blanks across multiple worksheets with averages

Tags: excel

Hi I have this code which will go through and replace blanks in my worksheet with an average, I need this to go through most worksheets but it doesn't run through all it only does 1 at the moment.

```
Sub FillBlanks()

Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets


Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

             Set rng2 = Range("L1:AB40")

             On Error Resume Next
             Set rng1 = rng2.SpecialCells(xlBlanks)

                 Application.Iteration = True
                 rng1.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-1]C,R[1]C)"
                 Application.Iteration = False
                 rng2.Value = rng2.Value

    Next ws 
End Sub
```

I was wondering what is missing from this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell it what worksheet Range("L1:AB40") is on.

```
Set rng2 = ws.Range("L1:AB40")
```

You could also use better error control in case there are no blanks.

```
Sub FillBlanks()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range

    For Each ws In Worksheets

         Set rng2 = ws.Range("L1:AB40")

         On Error Resume Next
         Set rng1 = rng2.SpecialCells(xlBlanks)
         on error goto 0

        if not rng1 is nothing then

             Application.Iteration = True
             rng1.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-1]C,R[1]C)"
             Application.Iteration = False
             rng2.Value = rng2.Value

        end if

    Next ws 

End Sub
```

Comment: How would I add into the code if I wanted to skip a couple of worksheets? I do know the names